# Javascript simple toggle not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I know this has been asked before in various places but i cannot understand why this is working. On toggle it should show/hide the div. Can some tell me why? Thanks

JS:

```
jQuery('.box-toggle.fl.active').on('click', function(event) {   
    jQuery('#box-content').toggle('show');
  });
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/amurray4/cwdt4xeL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery library in your project

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
```

***[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cwdt4xeL/3/)***

also, since you use an `anchor <a>` to register the click, in order to prevent page-jump-to-top following an anchor use `Event.preventDefault()`, and to secure your jQuery `$` alias use:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){ // Secured $ alias and DOM ready

  // Now use $ (for jQuery) freely:
  $('.box-toggle.fl.active').on('click', function(event) { 
    event.preventDefault();  
    $('#box-content').toggle('slow'); // Use "slow"
  });
  // other DO Mready code here

});
```

Comment: sorry... its not staying out for some reason? on toggle it flies out the flies back in. any ideas why?

Comment: @AlexMurray I have no clue. As you can see it works. That's all I can see :(

Comment: yeah weird... if i remove the display: none; it initially shows then flies in the flies out and shows again - so reversed. potentially something in my css

Comment: @AlexMurray :) I really cannot know, buy me a woodoo crystal globe and I'll be happy to help! (or simply post a fiddle with your new issue? :) )

Comment: ha i wish! i figured out that the javascript is running twice on click. any idea why that might be? cheers

Comment: @AlexMurray wait let me connect with your mind... ommmmm :D No, sorry I have no idea ;) Probably you have other handlers bound to that elements? Take a second look at all your code.